# TYPO3 shibboleth_auth alternative and extension customization

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

Since the TYPO3 forum seems a bit dead, I thought I'll try my luck here. If anyone knows a different place to ask, be sure to name it and I'll delete this post.

I recently acquired a project with TYPO3 webistes that I need to migrate from 6.2 to 7.6. I will probably need to rewrite a lot of customized extensions and I want to start with the login system. The main site uses [shibboleth_auth](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/shibboleth_auth) (which is discontinued) that has been partially rewritten to fetch login data from different endpoint.

Now, **what is the current alternative for this extension**? And **how do I "extend" an extension** so that It can still be upgraded, but also uses my methods? ( in this case, the custom endpoints for login verifications ).

Comment: It is the right place to ask (read here http://blog.montagmorgen.at/2016/09/06/moving-to-stackoverflow.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that the University of Austria and Munich are currently working on a shibboleth authentication plugin that will work with 7.6. They asked a couple of weeks ago about feature requests and funding.

Comment: Can you provide me with a link/source?

Answer (score 0):

Our agency is maintaining a friendly fork of EXT:shibboleth_auth, it can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/visol/shibboleth_auth) and [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/visol/shibboleth-auth). It is currently compatible with TYPO3 8.7 CMS and a version for TYPO3 10.4 LTS will follow shortly.